# Eliminar el borde "vacio" o blanco que me queda cuando coloco una background-image en React

Tags: css, reactjs

Necesito eliminar el borde "vacio" o blanco que me queda cuando coloco una background-image en el home. Estoy usando React y pense que tal vez el alguna propiedad predefinida. Se agradece ayuda.
Dejo el css y la imagen:

```
    body { margin:0;}
.home{
    background-image: url("../images/img.svg.svg");
  
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    
  
}
```

---

imagen de referencia:

[image: background-image]

Comment: Podrías integrar en tu 'css' un atributo que impacte en todas las etiquetas, tanto 'html' 'head' 'body' etc lo íntegras de la siguiente manera '*{padding:0; margin:0;}' esto hace que le saque los espacios que te pone por defecto cualquier navegador.